# Get Quicksort list as a whole to visualize while using recursion

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

So I wrote this method for Quicksort. I know it isn't the most efficient, but it is what I came along with. The plan is to have a list that shows the list as a whole so that I can visualize it in my GUI.

```
def quickSort(self, element_list=None):
        
        if element_list == None:
            element_list = self.data

        if len(element_list) < 2:
            return element_list  # Return a list with a single element

        pivot = element_list[-1]
        del element_list[-1]

        # List for values lower and higher than pivot
        splited_list = [[], []]

        for value in element_list:
            if value <= pivot:
                splited_list[0].append(value)
            else:
                splited_list[1].append(value)
        
        return self.quickSort(splited_list[0]) + [pivot] + self.quickSort(splited_list[1])
```

When using this list `[27, 13, 6, 42, 19, 8, 35, 11]` the list should look something like this over time:

```
[6, 8, 11, 27, 13, 42, 19, 35]
[6, 8, 11, 27, 13, 42, 19, 35]
[6, 8, 11, 27, 13, 19, 35, 42]
[6, 8, 11, 13, 19, 27, 25, 42]
```

I looked for different methods, but none of them worked and I'm out of ideas, so maybe one of you guys could help :)

Comment: You should modify the algorithm so it sorts the list *in-place*. Then you have one single list to print. Now you have bits and pieces that are local to separate scopes, so you don't have access to one list that has the intermediate order -- it just doesn't exist, so you can't print it either.

Comment: To further what @trincot wrote.  Usually quicksort uses a helper function `quicksort_internal(list, low, high)` that sorts the elements `low <= index < high` and uses that for recursion.

Comment: To be clear, if you're copying data to new lists it isn't Quicksort at all.